# Setting up an Apache VirtualHost for Symfony

Tags: symfony

Admittedly I am utterly new to Symfony and I am irritated.

I am using the docu here: [0]. After setting everything up with "symfony/apache-pack" I get the ".htaccess" file with heaps of stuff in the "/public" directory. Now I wanted to be smart and moved all the rewrite rules to a proper VirtualHost and deleted the "htaccess" file. BANG, the required script files are not being loaded from the vendor directory and not style appear on the website. After killing all rewrite rules from the VirtualHost we website is up and running again.

Because of this sentence "A performance improvement can be achieved by moving the rewrite rules from the .htaccess file into the VirtualHost block of your Apache configuration and then changing AllowOverride All to AllowOverride None in your VirtualHost block." I am confused now since it suggests that I imperatively need rewrite rules for Symfony.

Note that I changed to AllowOverride None.

Can anyone shed some light onto this. I somehow feel that I am doing something dead wrong.

[0] https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#web-server-apache-mod-php